# Activate conda env and run pip install requirements in the Dockfile

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile, conda, docker-build

I can create my virtual environment `dev1` successfully, but I can not activate it and switch into in during the Docker building.

All I want is to switch the venv and install my dependencies in `requirements.txt`.

My code:

```
WORKDIR /APP
ADD . /APP
ARG CONDA_VENV=dev1
RUN conda create -y --name ${CONDA_VENV} python=3.7
RUN conda activate ${CONDA_VENV}
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


The command '/bin/sh -c conda activate ${CONDA_VENV}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: A Docker image is an isolation environment in itself.  It's safe (and common) to `pip install` directly into the "system" Python; you don't need a virtual environment on top of this.

Comment: I agree with @DavidMaze - conda and its derivatives are not needed in docker.

Comment: Some packages can resolve dependecies with conda but not with pip.

Comment: Hey @Jet C. did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: there are plenty of good reasons to install conda in docker, and ot avoid system python even in docker. Many packages are very well tested with conda. And many people use docker like a remote vm to separate different dev environments.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in the same line. To install in `dev1` using pip:

```
RUN . /code/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate dev1\
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

To install in `dev1` using conda itself for packages that are in coda channels

```
RUN conda install -n dev1 packagname
```

Comment: Did you read first comment under the question? - Virtual environment is for escaping from `versioning hell` in python. There is no need to do what OP is asking about in Docker container.

Comment: There are plenty of packages that need to be run in conda. And having a docker to separate OS-level separation is also necessary. I use this to develop ML Cuda code with different CUDA/Pytorch versions, and cannot think of any better way than using both docker and conda